Without Banach-Steinhaus, can we prove the continuity of the bilinear form?

Let $B$ be a normed linear space, and let $f : {M}_{n}\left( \mathbb{R}\right)  \times  B \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}$ be a bilinear function, $f(\cdot,y)$ and $f(x,\cdot)$ are both continuous, prove that $f$ is continous. ${M}_{n}\left( \mathbb{R}\right)$ is the collection of all $n\times n$ matrices.

My attempt: By Riesz, $f(x,y)=(x,Ay)$, for a linea map $A: B\to {M}_{n}\left( \mathbb{R}\right) $, $(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the inner product in ${M}_{n}\left( \mathbb{R}\right) $.
$f(x,\cdot)$ is continuous, then $f(x,\cdot)$ is bounded at each $y\in B$. So by Banach-Steinhaus theorem, $\sup_{x\in {M}_{n}\left( \mathbb{R}\right) }||f(x,\cdot)||<\infty$.
Then how to do?

You can replace $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ by ay finite dimensional subspace.

Let $Z$ be a finite dimensional space with basis $\{e_k\}_{k=1}^n.$ Every element $z$ is uniquely represented as $z=\sum_{k=1}^n a_k(z)e_k.$ We introduce the norm on $Z$ by
$$\|z\|=\sum_{k=1}^n|a_k(z)| $$ The norm is not essential as all norms on $Z$ are equivalent. Then
$$f(z,x)=\sum_{k=1}^na_k(z)f(e_k,x) \quad (*)$$ By assumptions there are constants $c_k$ such that $$|f(e_k,x)|\le c_k\|x\|,\quad x\in X\quad (**)$$ Let $c=\max c_k.$ Then, in view of $(*)$ and $(**),$ we get
$$|f(z,x)|\le \sum_{k=1}^nc_k|a_k(z)|\,\|x\| \le  c\|z\|\|x\|$$
